# Why hostfwd option of QEMU need root access in some times and doesn't need some times

Tags: qemu, port-forwarding

This command of QEMU doesn't need root access :

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 3072 -smp 2 -hda Debian9.qcow2 -device e1000,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22,hostfwd=tcp::9000-:9000
```

When I added the 443 and 80 port, I need root access :

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -m 3072 -smp 2 -hda Debian9.qcow2 -device e1000,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22,hostfwd=tcp::9000-:9000,hostfwd=tcp::443-:443,hostfwd=tcp::80-:80
```

Without root access I've got this error message :

```
qemu-system-x86_64: -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22,hostfwd=tcp::9000-:9000,hostfwd=tcp::443-:443,hostfwd=tcp::80-:80: Could not set up host forwarding rule 'tcp::80-:80'
```

Is that meaning sort of TCP port access are protected in QEMU software ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ports < 1024 are [privileged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports), and only a root process (or a process with `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` [capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) in Linux) can bind a socket to them.

The host forwarding in qemu works by qemu binding a socket to a port on the host machine; if the qemu process is running as a normal user with no extra caps, it won't be able to bind to 80 or 443.

If you're on Linux, you can work around that with `setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE+ep /path/to/qemu-system-x86_64`, but that's something I do **not** recommend.